# ODBC drivers to access ESE edb file

Tags: odbc, extensible-storage-engine

are their any odbc drivers to access edb file on Windows 7.

I am trying to access edb file from Query Tool ODBC tool.But until i am not able to connect to the db.

Please let me know how to connect to edb file .Where can i find ODBC drivers for edb file. i checked in Microsoft documentation but all my efforts are in vain.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no ODBC, or OleDB, or any other drivers for the Extensible Storage Engine (ESE) database files.

There was some interest in CodePlex, but that's about as far as it has gotten.   I don't expect to see a driver at all... sorry